# Open file in ironpython by clicking on a button

Tags: ironpython

I would like to open a PDF document via a button. I don't seem to find what I need.
When the button is clicked, it will open the document based on the path provided (i.e. `"c:\test\abc.pdf"`).

Is there a main command that would open any document type as long as you have the full path (i.e. `"c:\test\abc.jpg"`, `"c:\test\abc.txt"`, etc...)?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're running on Windows, you could just run system commands directly to open the files.  If you were to directly "run" the file, the associated process will open it.

```py
import os
os.system(r'c:\test\abc.jpg')
```

This will however block until the process is closed, but you could call the `start` process to open the file for you.

```py
os.system(r'start c:\test\abc.jpg')
```

On the other hand, this is IronPython and you have direct access to the .Net framework.  You could use the `System.Diagnostics.Process` class to do the same in a relatively safer manner.

```py
from System.Diagnostics import Process
Process.Start(r'start c:\test\abc.jpg')
```